# OrientDB: how to speed up import from Blueprint Java API?

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm experiencing really slow data ingestion in OrientDB by using the Blueprint Java API.
Specifically, I'm loading ~ 1M nodes and 3M edges from several CSV files by using the `plocal` mode and the `OrientGraphNoTx` class (unfortunately I couldn't use the ETL since it does not allow me to read a file containing edges among existing nodes). 
The code is written in Scala and it run for approximately one and a half hour.

The schema of the database contains 5 vertex classes, 7 edge classes, and 6 indexes. Attributes I use to create edges are indexed by using `unique_hash_index`es.
Creating edges between existing nodes was the most time consuming operation (probably because there are many edges), below is the code I used.
Does anybody have any idea how to optimise it?

```
/**
 * Adds edges to the graph.
 * Assumes edgesPath points to a CSV file with format (from, to)
 */
def addEdges(edgesPath: String,
             fromTable: String, fromAttribute: String,
             toTable: String, toAttribute: String,
             edgeType: String, graph: OrientGraphNoTx) {

  logger.info(s"Adding edges from '$edgesPath'...")
  val in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(edgesPath), Charset.forName("utf-8"))
  val records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
    .withHeader("from", "to")
    .withSkipHeaderRecord(hasHeader)
    .parse(in)
  var errors = 0
  for (r <- records) {
    val (src, target) = (r.get("from"), r.get("to"))
    if (src != "" && target != "") {
      try {
        graph.command(new OCommandSQL(s"CREATE EDGE $edgeType FROM (" +
          s"SELECT FROM $fromTable WHERE $fromAttribute = '$src') " +
          s"TO (SELECT FROM $toTable WHERE $toAttribute ='$target')")).execute()
      } catch {
        case e: OCommandExecutionException => errors += 1
      }
    } //if
  } //for
  if(errors > 0)
    logger.warn(s"Couldn't create $errors edges due to missing sources/targets or internal errors")
  logger.info("done.")
} //addEdges
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in plocal and you need one batch import
try to disable the WAL for your importer

```
OGlobalConfiguration.USE_WAL.setValue(false);
```

Comment: thanks for the advice; it's running right now. I'll let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately there was really little improvement on the execution time :(